# unable to connect to wifi hp pavilion g seriers

Tags: wireless

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info \
    && chmod +x wireless-info \
    && ./wireless-info
```

above command output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/13987254/